# Swift: Create a Date() from a Google Drive API Timestamp

Tags: ios, swift, date, timestamp, dateformatter

I'm working with the Google Drive API in Swift, and one of the pieces of data I'm working with is a timestamp, formatted like this: 2021-04-18T22:50:33.235Z

I keep getting `nil` for my Date object, and I assume it has to do with my DateFormatter(), but I can't seem to figure out exactly what is wrong.

Here's my code that I tried:

```
var creationDateAsString = "2021-04-18T22:50:33.235Z"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: creationDateAsString) {
   //do what I need to do
}
```

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: I don't see a problem, in my playground (Swift 5.1) it works.

Comment: It works fine for me too, notice that you can also use a ISO8601DateFormatter here by setting the format options to `dateFormatter.formatOptions = [.withInternetDateTime,.withFractionalSeconds]`

Comment: Is your device showing 12h format? Could be the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's true that this code, for some reason, worked in the playground, but not in my actual Swift app. I was, however, able to solve the issue by defining the locale:

```
var creationDateAsString = "2021-04-18T22:50:33.235Z"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: creationDateAsString) {
    //do what I need to do
}
```